# Failure failing in CATCH

Tags: error-handling, raku

I'm probably overlooking something simple, but I do not expect the below code to fail. It is behaving as if I wrote `die` instead of `fail` in the catch block.

The Failure does not get properly handled and the code dies.

```
sub foo() 
{
  try {
    say 1 / 0;
    CATCH { default { fail "FAIL" } }
  } 

  return True;
}

with foo() { 
    say "done";
}
else
{
  say "handled {.exception.message}"
}
```

Output:

```
FAIL
  in block  at d:\tmp\x.pl line 5
  in any  at d:\tmp\x.pl line 5
  in sub foo at d:\tmp\x.pl line 4
  in block <unit> at d:\tmp\x.pl line 11
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To bring home to later readers the full force of [what Yoda said in their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58149618/failure-failing-in-catch#comment102683609_58149709), the simplest solution is to *unlearn* the notion that you have to `try` in order to `CATCH`. You don't:

```
sub foo() 
{
  say 1 / 0;
  CATCH { default { fail "FAIL" } }
  return True;
}

with foo() { 
    say "done";
}
else
{
  say "handled {.exception.message}"
}
```

correctly displays:

```
handled FAIL
```

Answer (score 4):

According to the Failure [documentation](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Failure) this seems to be the defined behavior.

> Sink (void) context causes a Failure to throw, i.e. turn into a normal exception. The use fatal pragma causes this to happen in all contexts within the pragma's scope. Inside try blocks, use fatal is automatically set, and you can disable it with no fatal.

You can try to use the `no fatal` pragma.

```
sub foo() {
try {
    no fatal;
    say 1 / 0;
    CATCH { default { fail "FAIL" } }
  }
}

unless foo()  {
     say "handled"
}
```

Comment: But it is not in sink context? `fail` "leaves the current routine and returns the provided Exception or Str wrapped inside a Failure", so foo should return a `Failure` that is handled by the `unless`.

Comment: There's also no requirement to put `CATCH` inside of `try`, which would provide a solution with *less* code than initially provided, not more.

Comment: @JonathanWorthington Huh? If I move the CATCH outside the `try` the error never gets caught. Like in the code above, if I do that, the program prints "done".

Comment: Oh. OH! You mean without the try block. I did not know you can do that